# Magento 2 products not being added to cart

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

The "Add to cart" button changes to "adding" and stays like that. It does nothing after that.It doesn't work from anywhere not even product details page.

[image: Magento products not going in cart]

Comment: give me the url of website

Comment: `http://localhost/magento2.0/home-furniture/sofa-armchairs.html`

Comment: this is localhost url give me server url..

Comment: i'm testing on localhost

Comment: ok check your console is there any error after clicking button

Comment: no there are no errors

Comment: Check magento log file for error descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

Change your base URL from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Using `localhost` as the domain in your base URL causes problems in Magento 2.

Magento's base URL configuration is located in the `core_config_data` table. The following `value`s may need to be changed:

- `web/unsecure/base_url`
- `web/secure/base_url`

For example, if you previously had `http://localhost/yourproject/`, you should change it to `http://127.0.0.1/yourproject/`

After changing the url, flush the cache (`bin/magento cache:flush`). You might also need to [clear out your var directories](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html).

Answer (score 1):

go to PHPMyAdmin coreconfigdata

change URL `localhost/project to 127.0.0.1/project`